# Django + Memcached: get all entries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, memcached

I would like to use Memcached and Django.

I need to store some entries key-value with an expiration  timeout. In this way,  using Memcached with expiration timeout, I can clear automatically all expired entries.

But I need also to retrieve all current stored entries.

Is there a way to get all contained entries in memcached using Django.

An example of my idea:

*We can suppose to store in cache the last users locations. I'm interested to store only the last user locations that I can receive form mobile app (for example) so, I can set a timeout (expiration) when I add a entry in the cache. In this way Memechached will clears automatically all expired entries and I not have to manage manually it. This is ok form me*

But I need also of a method to get all the actually contained entries (not expired).

I'm not found an api to retrieve all current entries using Django + Memcached.

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to show how you are storing them in the first place.

Comment: I haven't yet defined this but I was thinking of something like this:
cache.set('my_key', 'obj', 30)
I can use my custom key one for an entry. I think that is not important because I do not need to retrieve an entry by key or update it. I need only a way to store an entry and retrive all current saved entries